# occasional client error fullcalendar.js

Tags: fullcalendar, google-api-client

I am trying to help sort a friend's issue with their fullcalendar.js implementation.
The problem thus far is the events not loading consistently. Before uploading it to the Godaddy domain it worked every time but is spotty at best now. I looked at the Google developers tools and the credentials are all squared but saw that there is a client error happening however, I'm not sure where to look to fix an occasional problem? I am led to believe it is some sort of server issue but don't know where to start looking.

I don't have any rep so no pics, here is a link to the dashboard.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x1xfuyonavxz3vi/Screen%20Shot%202015-01-07%20at%2010.42.53%20PM.png?dl=0

Any help would be amazing, thanks!

Edit:
I contacted Godaddy to no avail, they said it was Google's issue and I should contact them.. which isn't possible without paying for it.. 
 Also, I found a work around: if I refresh the page navigate away and return it loads correctly.. any ideas on how to code it so if it fails to load I can get the same process?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone else, but...

I fixed my problem by changing the hierarchy of my files. I moved the calendar to the public html folder instead of the nested html folder. It seems as if the Jquery request to Google was getting interrupted or bogged down somehow, but, thus far I'm digging the 100% success rate. If anyone cares to weigh-in further, I'm happy to hear other suggestions.